# Pass logged user to model field django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I don't know how to get the username from the current user.

I have a edit form rendered with `djano-crispy-forms`:

```
class RecepcionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fecha_recepcion = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(RecepcionForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('id_proveedor',
                  'anio',
                  'mes',
                  'usuario',
                  readonly = True
             ),
            Fieldset('',
                     'fecha_recepcion',
                     'num_archivos',
                     Submit('save','Grabar')
            )
       )
    class Meta:
       model = DetalleRecepcion
```

my `views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def RecepcionView(request):
    idp = request.GET.get('i')
    anio = request.GET.get('a')
    mes = request.GET.get('m')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = RecepcionForm(request.POST, instance=r)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = RecepcionForm(instance=r)

    return render_to_response('recepcion.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I need to fill the field `usuario` with the logged username.
I tried with `form = request.user.username` before the save of the form.
I am confused of this have to be done passed the value in the form definition or in the view.

If is possible to overwrite the retrieved value from the database and fill the field with the username in the form class.

Another question
How can I change the widget type in the form. The field id_proveedor is a foreign key and is rendered as a drop down box (select widget), but I need to show the value displayed in a label where the can't edit the value.
I tried with the readonly propertie, but the user is not capable to write in the select box, but is capable to select from the drop down.
How can change the widget or how can I disabled the drop dwon function from the select box

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can get username by `request.user.username`.

Comment: You need to post a different question for the widget type.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass whatever arguments or keyword arguments you need to a form class, you just have to remove them from the `*args` or `**kwargs` that are passed on when calling `super()`, otherwise Django will throw an exception because it's receiving an `arg` or `kwarg` it's not expecting:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')  # notice the .pop()
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# views.py

def my_view(request):
    # assuming the user is logged in
    form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solve the issue with `instance.usuario = request.user`

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question, but I hope my code example will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same as your problem and found a solution just now. I do not know whether this is the best solution or maybe I will have problem later.

```
def add_trip_event(request):
#form = Trip_EventForm()
#return render(request, 'trips/add_trip_event.html', {'form': form})

if request.method == "POST":
    form = Trip_EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.trip_owner = Owner.objects.get(owner=request.user)
        post.pub_date = timezone.now()
        post.view = 0
        post.save()
        form.save_m2m()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('trips:index'))
else:
    form = Trip_EventForm()
return render(request, 'trips/add_trip_event.html', {'form': form})
```